# Why do I lose my images when I deploy my react app to gh-pages?

Tags: reactjs, image, firefox, directory, github-pages

My react site is deployed on gh-pages at:
https://efraimkrug.github.io/nehiezra/

When I use firefox to "inspect element" of
the (2) pictures that do not show, it shows me
the directory (without the base).

If I "copy link" and put it in the another
browser tab - the copy grabs also the base and
i see the picture!

If you know of any places where I can find more
information on how react and gh-pages treat
their links and base directory structures,
I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have hardcoded the image path by yourself. Try using the below path for quick workaround.

`images/RebNehemiaSmall.jpeg`

Alternatively and ideally, you can put image somewhere in your src folder, import in the component, and use the reference in the `src` attribute of `img` tag as below.

```
import myImage from './../somepath/RebNehemiaSmall.jpeg';
...
...
<img src={myImage} alt="My Image" />
```

Also, don't miss to set the document base url since you are deploying to a subdirectory.
Please check [this](https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory) if you are not aware about it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments. I am still not clear on how the build treats directories, but I have enough information to move forward in a more productive way.